# Analysis- convergence of functions pointwise problem

Tags: analysis

[image]

**Ok I HAVE COMPLETED THE FIRST PART**, however for the second part with the restriction on fn(x) I cant find a sequence of functions (I can find a sequence of functions but the integral does converge to 0 unfortunately), im guessing after thinking about this there isnt a sequence of functions but I'm not sure how to prove this.

Thanks

Comment: Think of the dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker i havent come across that theorem before, would you say theorem is pretty conclusive in terms of how to solve the question above?

Comment: Yes, every solution to the second part will effectively bol down to using some form of it.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker is it possible you could possibly give me an example of such an function, so I could possibly see the shape- i will read about the theorem but its a theorem I wont be learning this year at uni

Comment: No, it is not possible for me to give an example of such a function.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker right so its not possible, ok I will try to construct a proof using the theorem. thanks

Comment: Are you self-studying the Cambridge [Part IB](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/study/IB/AnalysisII/2013-2014/13sheet1.pdf)? Good luck!